# How to update image by a developer that is set into a imageview by load(url) method of glide?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am new in android app developing and got stuck in this problem. To understand my problem -

Let, I am a developer and I have an app. The app has a imageview. In that imageview, the image will be loaded using glide load(url) method from my(developer) website. Now I(developer)  want to change the image that will be shown in the app same imageview. But if I change the image the image url will be changed and glide load(url) method will not be able to download new image? How can I solve this problem or what topic should learn to handle this issue or what is the alternative?

Comment: lol...why do you keep calling yourself a developer? sounds crazy. if you have an image http://www.website.com/image.jpg.... all you need to do is upload a image with the same name at the same location and you should be good. if you cache that image...thats why its not updating. however, i (developer) would use firebase or parse to update my (developer) app.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I upload a image of same name at same location in blogspot site? 

Here, I have used the word 'let' as the synonym of the word 'suppose'. I did it just to make you understand my problem. May be I have used inappropriate word and sorry for that.

Comment: if you want to use a difference image inside of an imageview, using a URL, then you need to have access to the actual backend (FTP) of the site. I doubt blogspot allows that. you can use firebase and just store the image there and then change it. that should work. but you wont be using glide....

Answer (score 1):

1. Download image
2. Save to disk (optional)
3. Modify image (optional)
4. Show modified image in `ImageView`.

(You don't need glide here)